# How to pass a username from a Django login form?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

This will be an easy question for someone out there. I searched around quite a bit and if there's a thread that addresses this perfectly, please direct me and close this out. I'm building a very simple web form within our organization's website using Django.

In forms.py I've got a class for the login page:

```
class userLogin(forms.Form):

    user = forms.CharField(label = 'Username ', max_length = 25)
    pwd  = forms.CharField(label = 'Password ', widget = forms.PasswordInput)

    def clean(self):

        cleaned_data = super(userLogin, self).clean()
        user         = cleaned_data.get("user")
        pwd          = cleaned_data.get("pwd")

        if not fs.authenticateUser(user, pwd):
            raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid password!")
```

I have to authenticate against our website's API, which is what the fs.authenticate bit is about; it just returns True or False. In views.py I do this:

```
    if request.method == 'POST':

        user_form = userLogin(data = request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid():            
            return redirect('PickupAuthorization/main')
        else:
            pass
```

The authentication and redirection to the main page works splendidly, and the login form throws an invalid password message as expected when the credential is incorrect. What I want to know is how to make "user" available to views.py. If I try to reference user_form.user in the view, Python tells me that user is not an attribute of userLogin!

I haven't done much with OOP, so I'm imagining that this has a simple answer, but I can't freakin' find it. Thanks!

EDIT: I have had to shelve this project for the moment in favor of more pressing matters, but I will update it when I have a solution that works properly.

Comment: You do not need to re-invent the wheel, take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/

Comment: I took a look at this and I get it through where it talks about the AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS  setting. But then it discusses writing my own authentication backend, which I _think_ is what I need to do, because I'm using a third-party API. Yet, I'm unclear as to how to return a User object. If I'm reading the documentation at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#user-objects correctly, I'd need to do something like `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` and then `user = User.objects.create_user` - utilizing the authenticated username, yes?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `authenticate` method provided by `Django` in order to get the user. The `authenticate` method returns a user if it finds one. 

To `authenticate` a given `username` and `password`, use `authenticate()`. It takes two keyword arguments, `username` and `password`, and it returns a `User object` if the `password` is valid for the given `username`. If the `password` is invalid, `authenticate()` returns `None`:

Generally the flow using `authenticate` goes like this:

**forms.py**

```
class userLogin(forms.Form):

    user = forms.CharField(label = 'Username ', max_length = 25)
    pwd  = forms.CharField(label = 'Password ', widget =  forms.PasswordInput)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user_cache = None # You need to make the user as None initially
        super(LoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):

        cleaned_data = super(userLogin, self).clean()
        user         = cleaned_data.get("user")
        pwd          = cleaned_data.get("pwd")

        # Now you get the user
        self.user_cache = authenticate(username=user, password=pwd)
        # Do other stuff
        return self.cleaned_data

    # Function to return user in views
    def get_user(self):
        return self.user_cache
```

**Views.py**

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    user_form = userLogin(data = request.POST)
    # You can now get user using the get_user method
    user = user_form.get_user()

    # Do other stuff
```

Another thing I'd like to add is if your user has already logged in you can simply do `request.user.username` in your `views.py` to get the current user.

Comment: Okay, I understand what you're saying...but as I mention in my response to @Wtower above, it seems that I need to write my own authentication backend, because I'm authenticating via our website's API. I'd then add my backend to AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS in settings.py and Django would in turn use it when I make the call `self.user_cache = authenticate(username=user, password=pwd)`, yes?

Comment: I followed your structure and it authenticates fine, but in views.py when I go `user = user_form.get_user()`, and then try to print out `user.usernames`, I get that usernames is not an attribute of user. But the documentation clearly states that username is an attribute of a User object. What am I not understanding?

Comment: @PatJones print out the `user` and let me know what it prints. Also do you have a user model? Is so please add the code above.